# How to set up VS Code for WP plugin/theme development in 2021?

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development, formatting, ide

I'm trying to improve my WP theme and plugin development workflow.
VS Code is my editor/IDE of choice and I'm pretty with it in general.

However, setting up VS Code with debugging, formatting, linting etc. for PHP, js and (s)css for WP ended up in quite a struggle.

There are various good tutorials about how to achieve this, i.e.

- [Linting and Formatting in Visual Studio Code for WordPress](https://sridharkatakam.com/linting-and-formatting-in-visual-studio-code-for-wordpress/)
- [Setting Up PHP CodeSniffer in Visual Studio Code](https://tommcfarlin.com/php-codesniffer-in-visual-studio-code/)
- [Sniffer, Linter, Pretty Printer](https://github.com/christophherr/linter-sniffer-pretty-printer)
- [Set Up Visual Studio Code and xDebug as the Ultimate Editor for WordPress Development](https://deliciousbrains.com/vs-code-wordpress/)

But they are somewhat dated and the versions of WP, VS Code, PHP, VSC-extensions etc. changed a lot over the past years. In addition, even some of the WP style guide repos seem to be deprecated (i.e. [stylelint-config-wordpress](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/stylelint-config-wordpress)).
And many of the recommended VSC extensions haven't been updated for months or years.

Wordpress runs a big percentage of the web and VS Code is one of the most popular editors nowadays. I'm sure there is way to set this up nicely.

It would be great if someone could point me to an up-to-date documentation or tutorial.
Or if someone is willing to help me setting it up, I'm happy to write down the tutorial myself and publish it somewhere for others.

**Update**
I started writing the "tutorial", at least for the things I already figured out
[Github:WordPress-VSCode-Dev](https://github.com/stingray21/WordPress-VSCode-Dev)